# Understanding Callback function

Tags: javascript

i have trouble with the following code:

```
var placeingOrders = function(orderNumber) {
    console.log("Order number: ", orderNumber);
    requestedOrder(orderNumber, returnOrder);
};

function requestedOrder(orderNumber, callback) {
    setTimeout(orderNumber, callback, 5000);
}

function returnOrder() {
    console.log("Order number: " ,  " is delivered");
}
```

im trying to pass arguments on callback function but when i do as above i got the following error code:

```
timers.js:348
    throw new TypeError('"callback" argument must be a function');
    ^

TypeError: "callback" argument must be a function
    at exports.setTimeout (timers.js:348:11)
```

And of course if i run the same code without arguments it will work.

```
var placeingOrders = function(orderNumber) {
    console.log("Order number: ", orderNumber);
    requestedOrder(returnOrder);
};

function requestedOrder(callback) {
    setTimeout(callback, 5000);
}

function returnOrder() {
    console.log("Order number: " , orderNumber , " is delivered");
}
```

I would like to know what im exactly doing wrong here. How do i use this callback function correctly if i want to pass arguments.

(ps: im not a native english speaker, sry for that)

Comment: requestedOrder(orderNumber, returnOrder); returnOrder is not defined and you dont set it to call the function requestedOrder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Why you get this error ?**

`setTimeout` expects to get the callback function **as the first argument**, but at the first place you pass a number, so why the exception. The second case works, because you remove the `orderNumber` from the first place, an the function gets it.

You need to pass the arguments of the callback function after the 2nd place. See the [**setTimeout**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) function signature. First goes the callback function, 2nd - the time, at least to call the function and after it everything which are passed goes to the callback function as arguments.

This is the signature of the function - `[]` are optional ones.

```
setTimeout(function[, delay, param1, param2, ...])
```

Code

```js
var placeingOrders = function(orderNumber) {
   console.log("Order number: ", orderNumber);
   requestedOrder(orderNumber, returnOrder);
};
    
function requestedOrder(orderNumber, callback) {
    setTimeout(callback, 5000, orderNumber);
}
    
function returnOrder(orderNumber) {
    console.log("Order number: " + orderNumber +  " is delivered");
}

placeingOrders(14);
```

Comment: You will also want to give `returnOrder` a parameter and actually use it somewhere

Comment: The Params passed after delay are not always passed to the callback, using an anonymous self invoking function would be safer

Comment: `are not always passed to the callback` - can you clarify a bit?